# Error when using TortoiseGit diff command with new added file in commit

Tags: git, tortoisegit, git-diff

I try to make my custom program working with git. Some task like compare difference between two files I just create new process and run TortoiseGit Commands like this

```
/command:diff /startrev:20404fc1039ce9ee73f0d16213319afe480b0a05 /endrev:294e111888ed87a8c93a898f6e6f061b15250e0d /path:D:/Project/ReportingTool/Src/Reports.Types/Report.cs
```

**On modified committed file**, I got the same result as TortoiseGit UI.
[picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrPjR.png)

**the problem is, on new added committed file** there are no file in previous revision to checkout to compare. an error says

```
failed to checkout file "files/powershell/App_BuildAndDeploy.ps1" of 
revision 62f7869c1780e6501ec1c4dc0387f03efbde10da to 
"C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Temp\TortoiseGit\AppAAD3.tmp\App_BuildAndDeploy-
62f7869-left.ps1" libgit2 returned:the path 'App_BuildAndDeploy.ps1' does 
not exist in the given tree
```

How to get a result like TortoiseGit like this picture, [desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hN55y.png).

i know i can just create new empty file somewhere and use it to compare but i am not sure that is the best/correct way to do it

Comment: I have a quick review on the TortoiseGit source code. Looks like there is no way to do that by using command **diff**. Want to fire a TortoiseGit issue? Then, go https://tortoisegit.org/issues.

Comment: @YueLinHo new issue was created, thank you for your suggestion. I will keep updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue in older versions of TortoiseGit and [is fixed](https://tortoisegit.org/issue/3028) in TortoiseGit 2.5.0.

Please note: That `/startrev:` and `/endrev:` parameters were mixed up in older versions, you might need to ajust these values.